# probability of lottery game with a guarantee

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A company claimed that the probability of get a rewards from their lottery is 0.5%. They also guaranteed that a player will get one reward in 60th lottery, if that player failed to obtain the reword in the past 59 lotteries.

If a player takes n lotteries, what is the true probability for per lottery?

Under 60 lotteries:

0.005

With 60 lotteries, the reward rate is guaranteed system + a general rate:

(60*0.005 + $(1-0.005)^{59}$)/60 which is 0.017399681033445635

How to calculate it when n > 60,the reward rate is guaranteed system + a general rate:

(n*0.005 + times of guaranteed system occur)/n

I just noticed that the probability will increasing with n increasing, but I do not know does there exist a boundary. In some points, the probability will over the 1.9%.

```
import random
total = 0
count = 0
n=1800
for j in range(2000):
    bot = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if bot == 59:
            bot = 0
            count = count+1
        elif random.random() <=0.005:
            bot = 0
            count = count + 1
        else:
            bot = bot +1
        total = total+1

print(count/total)
```

Comment: This is very confusing.  In the first sentence it seems the claim is that contestants win  $1.9\%$ of the time in one lottery.  All the rest seems focused on having a $1.9\%$ chance of winning at least one prize in a series of lotteries.  It is also not clear what the question is.  Please clarify.

Comment: You can ignore the first sentance, and I will delete it. The "1.9%" is just a claim, it means nothing. The True rate is 0.05% basic rate + the guarante system.

Answer (score 0):

If you play $60$ times, your chance of never winning without the guarantee is $0.995^{60} \approx 0.74$.  Your expected number of wins is then $60 \cdot 0.005+0.74=1.04$.  The fraction of times you win is then $\frac {1.04}{60} \approx 1.73333\%$  If you play less than $60$ times, you get no benefit from the guarantee so your fraction of wins is $0.5\%$.  Clearly you should play in multiples of $60$ as the guarantee is quite valuable.

Comment: the issue is, the probability will increasing as the drawing time increasing after 60th play. I get this result from program simulation. Playing inmultiples of 60 it not a good choice in this case.

Comment: After the 60th play it sounds like you are back at the start.  You have gotten the guaranteed payout so the clock starts over.  Similarly, if you win before game 60, it sounds like the clock starts over.  Am I misunderstanding the rules?

Comment: A example for the guarente system, if you play 120 times, the 1st to the 59th, and 61th to 119 th does not win a reword, you will get a reward in 60th  and 120th draw. Play 120 draws again, if you win a reword in 30th draw, and do not get reeword in 31th to 89th, you will get a reword in 90th draw.

Comment: That is how I was understanding it.  In that case, what do you mean the probability is increasing when $n$ is increasing.  The probability of a win in a given draw is fixed.  Yes, the probability of at least one win is increasing.

Comment: I use program to simulated it. The  probability (to draw a reword) is increasing when n increasing. When n is around to 1800, the probability is close to 1.9%. The probability of a win in a given baisc draw is fixed, but the total probability is increasing with a guarantee system.

Comment: Then I think your program is not telling you what you think.  Once you win, it is as if you had never played going forward because the counter for the guarantee is reset.

Comment: It is, I add my code in the question. You can try.